# Error al intentar actualizar pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, certificado-ssl

Hola buenas mi problema es el siguiente.

Al poner la línea de código:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --upgrade pip
```

Me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\luist\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (22.3.1)
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
     - 523.2 kB 6.6 MB/s 0:00:00
ERROR: Wheel 'pip' located at C:\Users\luist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-43mmdgb2\pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl is invalid.
```

Las soluciones que he probado han sido:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade certifi
```

Y tambien:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Las dos soluciones me llevan a este error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\luist\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (22.3.1)
Collecting pip
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /packages/07/51/2c0959c5adf988c44d9e1e0d940f5b074516ecc87e96b1af25f59de9ba38/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /packages/07/51/2c0959c5adf988c44d9e1e0d940f5b074516ecc87e96b1af25f59de9ba38/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /packages/07/51/2c0959c5adf988c44d9e1e0d940f5b074516ecc87e96b1af25f59de9ba38/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /packages/07/51/2c0959c5adf988c44d9e1e0d940f5b074516ecc87e96b1af25f59de9ba38/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /packages/07/51/2c0959c5adf988c44d9e1e0d940f5b074516ecc87e96b1af25f59de9ba38/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/07/51/2c0959c5adf988c44d9e1e0d940f5b074516ecc87e96b1af25f59de9ba38/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:992)')))


[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.0.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Alguien tiene la solución para este problema?

Comment: Pareciera un paquete corrupto en el caché. Intenta usar: `python -m pip install --upgrade <el_paquete> --no-cache-dir`. También instala (o actualiza) el paquete `wheel` con el comando anterior.

Comment: hola buenas, gracias por tu contestación, acabo de empezar en este mundo, me podrias especificar cual es el archivo en concreto que esta corrupto? Si no es una molestia.